# Create Framework for raw data or Binary read and write

Tags: java, arrays, bytecode-manipulation

I am working on one project in which data has to read in binary format but one can put into a structure format. In java Structure is not available. I have send the data in byte array. It also has some structure.

For Example

Packet

```
int length 
int sequence no
MessageData
```

MessageData
   MessageHeader 
   MessageBody

MessageHeader
   int data1
   long data2 
   char[] data3//2bytes
   char[] data4//3 bytes

Same for MessageBody

But data should be packed in byte array.

One can do in CPP as

```
#pragma(2) //for word alignment

struct Packet{
    int length 
    int sequence no
    MessageData msgdata

}
```

I have to implement in java.

for reading data I am using [Preon](http://preon.codehaus.org/) library

But for writing data I am still using normal method for packaging data in byte array with help of some function 
Anybody have work on same kind project or have better idea

Comment: If you are reading using the Preon library, I suggest you write using it as well. Otherwise you need to know how it expects your data to be structured. My guess is you intend to use a byte[] for the text rather than a char[] (char is 16-bit in Java)

Comment: Yes, it is in byte[]. I don't know how write using Preon lib. If you have code then please post it. I didn't find any help or documentation on net.

Answer (score 0):

The current codebase does contain some bytes for writing data, however, it's not completed yet. Having said that, it might work for your current case:

```
Codec<Packet> codec = Codecs.create(Packet.class);
Packet packet = ...;
OutputStream out = ...;
codecs.encode(packet, codec, out);
```